# Filter and edit DB row Android studio

Tags: java, android, database, project

I have making project with DB and I have layout with two edittexts in that edittext on activity start I load one column from my DB and display it and in other edittext is text with I want to find specific row in DB table.

When I find that row I need to edit some values in this row. Here is my updatecode in DBadapter.java

```
// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(long containercode_row, String lkwnummer,String uniqueid, String containerbarcode,
                         String timein, String timeout, String howout, String latitudein,
                         String longitudein, String latitudeout, String longitudeout, String status) {
    String where = KEY_CONTAINERBARCODE + "=" + containercode_row;


    // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
    // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
    // Create row's data:
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_LKWNUMMER, lkwnummer);
    newValues.put(KEY_UNIQUEID, uniqueid);
    newValues.put(KEY_CONTAINERBARCODE, containerbarcode);
    newValues.put(KEY_TIMEIN, timein);
    newValues.put(KEY_TIMEOUT, timeout);
    newValues.put(KEY_HOWOUT, howout);
    newValues.put(KEY_LATITUDEIN, latitudein);
    newValues.put(KEY_LONGITUDEIN, longitudein);
    newValues.put(KEY_LATITUDEOUT, latitudeout);
    newValues.put(KEY_LONGITUDEOUT, longitudeout);
    newValues.put(KEY_STATUS, status);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}
```

I need to find row throught KEY_CONTAINERCODE value but I don't know how to make this code in activity where I want to find that row and edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can update your values by making a method in CommonUtill file like this:

```
public int updateRecords(String table, ContentValues values,
                             String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
        int a = db.update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
        return a;
    }
```

there is no need for creating a separate method for this for good practices.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i dont know how to use this code in my activity